# jest error when using gulp build in sharepoint framework project

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, gulp

In a SPFX project  I am following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/implement-ci-cd-with-azure-devops

Executing Unit Tests section.

I did install jest locally and then I run gulp build locally but I get lots of errors:

```
 gulp build
Build target: DEBUG
[10:05:07] Using gulpfile ~\source\repos\hellworld-webpart\gulpfile.js
[10:05:07] Starting gulp
[10:05:07] Starting 'build'...
[10:05:07] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[10:05:07] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 5.85 ms
[10:05:07] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[10:05:07] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 8.74 ms
[10:05:07] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[10:05:07] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[10:05:08] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 31 ms
[10:05:08] Finished subtask 'sass' after 186 ms
[10:05:08] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[10:05:08] [tslint] tslint version: 5.12.1
[10:05:09] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[10:05:09] [tsc] typescript version: 3.3.4000
[10:05:13] Warning - tslint - src\webparts\helloWorld\tests\webPartName.spec.ts(1,14): error semicolon: Missing semicolon
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.d.ts(7,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(7,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(8,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(9,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(10,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(11,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/SearchSource.d.ts(11,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.d.ts(9,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.d.ts(11,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.d.ts(11,25): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.d.ts(11,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/BaseReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/BaseReporter.d.ts(7,67): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/BaseReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/BaseReporter.d.ts(8,70): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(7,51): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.d.ts(10,61): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(7,67): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/DefaultReporter.d.ts(10,51): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(7,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(7,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(8,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(8,62): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(8,69): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(15,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(15,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(15,80): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.d.ts(15,87): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(7,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/NotifyReporter.d.ts(10,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(7,39): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/SummaryReporter.d.ts(10,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(7,75): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/VerboseReporter.d.ts(10,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(8,38): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(9,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(10,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/reporters/node_modules/@jest/types/build/Config.d.ts(10,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/formatTestResults.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/formatTestResults.d.ts(7,106): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/helpers.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/helpers.d.ts(7,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/helpers.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/helpers.d.ts(8,70): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/index.d.ts(9,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/index.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/index.d.ts(9,243): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/@jest/test-result/build/index.d.ts(9,250): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(11,40): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(11,50): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(29,77): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(29,83): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(339,53): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/emittery/index.d.ts(339,59): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.d.ts(8,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.d.ts(8,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.d.ts(9,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.d.ts(9,329): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.d.ts(7,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
[10:05:13] Error - [tsc] node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.d.ts(7,29): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[10:05:13] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 5.3 s
[10:05:13] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 4.21 s 
 exited with code 2
[10:05:13] 'build' errored after 5.52 s
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution for this?